# MVC - How to render a 'a href' link in a CSHTML on a HTML and PDF that's been stored in a database

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have an MVC app with CSHTML view

There are 2 question, that have text as "This is the website [Google](https://google.com/) to search."
The text is stored in DB and displayed on the cshtml page which will be rendered as HTML and PDF.

**The issue is the link on the html and PDF is rendered as below**

```
"This is the website <a href="https://google.com/">Google</a> to search."
```

as whole text

However I need it to be rendered as "This is the website  [Google](https://google.com/) to search." (where Google as hyperlink)

I am rendered questions as below - it is working fine for other question, but need to render the hyperlink correctly.

```
@foreach (var question in @Model.Questions)
        {
            
            <p>
                <div>@question.Description</div>
                <div style="padding-left:10px;">-@question.Answer</div>
            </p>
        }
```

Can you please help and advice for rendering the hyperlink correctly on HTML and PDF.

Comment: What are you using to create this PDF? You need to show that code as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by adding the Model value inside @Html.Raw()

```
Eg : <div>@Html.Raw(@question.Question1)</div>
```

Hope this would be helpful to someone :)